# OpenCV output on V4l2

Tags: opencv, v4l2

I wanted to know if I can use "opencv" to write on a v4l2 device.
I would take a picture, apply small changes with the features of opencv, and then send it on a v4l2 device.

I searched on the web, but there are a lot of examples on how to read from a V4L2 device, but I found nothing about writing on v4l2.

can someone help me?

Answer (score 10):

The question is 8 month old, but if you still need an answer (I suppose your OS is Linux):

1. Install  [`v4l2 loopback`](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) module

   1.1. Load and configure it `linux: i.e. modprobe.conf: options v4l2loopback video_nr=22,23`
2. Use such `C++/OpenCV` code: [`gist`](https://gist.github.com/thearchitect/96ab846a2dae98329d1617e538fbca3c)

   2.1. Setup device using ioctl() call

   2.2. Write raw RGB data to this device (i.e. `/dev/video23`)

   2.3. Use it as regular v4l2 device (i.e. webcam or `vlc v4l2:///dev/video23`)

more: You can use `ffmpeg` with `v4l2 loopback`:
`ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 12 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 -vf 'scale=800:600' /dev/video22`

Comment: How do you write raw RGB to the device?

Comment: @Genom (and users who find this in the future) - in the gist, the output device is initialized starting around line 69 and then written to at the end of the while loop.  Not exactly what you wanted. :D  The short answer is that you essentially write to the loopback device as in a regular file.  http://wonderingcode.blogspot.com/2017/05/loopback-with-python-and-opencv.html helps in python.