# Write to dummy video stream using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, v4l2, v4l, v4l2loopback

I'm using OpenCV and v4l2loopback library to emulate video devices:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2
```

Then I check what devices I have:

```
root@blah:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
        /dev/video1

Dummy video device (0x0001) (platform:v4l2loopback-001):
        /dev/video2

XI100DUSB-SDI (usb-0000:00:14.0-9):
        /dev/video0
```

video0 is my actual camera where I grab frames from, then I plan to process them via OpenCV and write it to video2 (which is a sink I believe).

Here is how I attempt to do so:

```
  int width = 320;
  int height = 240;
  Mat frame(height, width, CVX_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
  cvtColor(frame, frame, CVX_BGR2YUV);

  int fourcc = CVX_FOURCC('Y', 'U', 'Y', '2');
  cout << "Trying to open video for write: " << FLAGS_out_video << endl;
  VideoWriter outputVideo = VideoWriter(
      FLAGS_out_video, fourcc, 30, frame.size());
  if (!outputVideo.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "Could not open the output video for write: " << FLAGS_out_video
         << endl;
  }
```

As far as I know video output format should be `YUYV` (which is equal to `YUY2` in OpenCV). Please correct me if I'm wrong. In my code I'm not writing into `outputVideo` anything yet, just trying to open it for write, but I keep getting `outputVideo.isOpened()==false` for some reason, no additional errors/info in the output:

```
root@blah:~$ main --uid='' --in_video='0' --out_video='/dev/video2'
Trying to open video for write: /dev/video2
Could not open the output video for write: /dev/video2
```

I'd appreciate any advice or help on how to debug/resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just some guesses: 1) use a filename with extension, e.g. `/dev/video2.mpeg` 2) you don't have necessary codec installed, try another one to see if this is the case, 3) you don't have the permission to write in that folder

Comment: @Pavel Podlipensky: as far as i know it is not possible with the VideoWriter class. but you can write to the device directly. take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416189/opencv-output-on-v4l2